# Typescript load module fail via AMD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, typescript, amd

I made AngularJs app by typescript. and use requireJs load 'js(compiled ts) file'

I made simple controller A

myCtrl.ts

```
module myApp {
 'use strict';
 interface myMessage extends ng.IScope {
 message: string;
}
export class myCtrl {
 constructor($scope: myMessage) {
   $scope.message = "hello world";
  }
 }
}
```

and I load myApp file in main.ts

myApp.ts

```
import myController = require('./myCtrl');
module myApp{
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);
}
angular.bootstrap(document,['myAppDo']);
```

load was success but $scope.message not changed.

```
'Cannot read property 'myCtrl' of undefined'
```

when I change myApp.ts it work's fine

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ($scope, $http) => {
  $scope.message = "hello";
});
angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);
```

how can I Solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. first, add 'export' the controller module

```
module myApp
```

to

```
export module myApp
```

then specify the path

```
import myCtrl = require('./myCtrl');
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);
```

to

```
import myCtrl = require('./myCtrl');
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',myCtrl.myApp.myCtrl);
```

it seems something is wrong, but it work

Answer (score 0):

### Steps

1. Add `AMD-dependency`
2. Import module

### Result code

```
///<amd-dependency path="here path to your module"/>

import myController = require('myCtrl');
```

Comment: I tried, but myController can't access the myCtrl class too